# Так что же означает "хэшируемый"

Tags: python, хеширование, networkx

Я хочу что бы вершины моего графа в networkx были элементы моего класса. Согласно документации это должен быть какой то хэшируемый объект.

Так. Хэшируемый? Что это значит?. Согласно [офф документации](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) он должен иметь магические методы hash и eq. Вот мой класс:

```
class Task:
  def __init__(self, user_id, level, created_by_id):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.level = level
    self.created_by_id = created_by_id
  
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.user_id == other.user_id:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.user_id)
```

У него есть оба этих метода, но когда я пытаюсь:

```
t1 = Task(...)
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_node(t1)
```

Выводит ошибку

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Task'
```

Comment: Если сделать методы приватными, то все вроде работает.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `user_id` однозначно определяет ваши объекты, это уникальный идентификатор? Если нет, то при хэшировании и сравнении нужно учитывать все поля, которые делают объект уникальным, иначе могут быть проблемы с идентификацией объектов.

Comment: А так то в Google Colab не ругается на ваш код

Comment: @CrazyElf обычно user_id (как и любой другой uid) подразумевает же уникальность... тут, скорее всего, id пользователя в бд, должен быть уникальным

Comment: @Jack_oS Ну тогда вообще проблем нет )

Comment: user_id действительно уникальный. Так что по идеи все должно работать правильно. Но если поле не приватное, то выходит ошибка, хотя по идее объект хэшируемый

Comment: Да, user_id это точно уникальное поле и мне достаточно сравнить его